# How to save a in-application edited txt file in java

Tags: java, file, save

I'm stuck on how to save a file in a text editor i'm creating.Here's my code if you can help me

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;


import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.*;


public class test1 {

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Press to read a file");
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel ();
        middlePanel.setBorder ( new TitledBorder ( new EtchedBorder (), "Text Reading Box" ) );

        // create the middle panel components

        final JTextArea display = new JTextArea ( 16, 58 );
        display.setEditable ( false);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane ( display );
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );

        //Add Text area in to middle panel
        middlePanel.add ( scroll );

        // My code
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Text Reader 0.4 Beta"); 
        frame.add ( middlePanel );
        frame.add(b1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible ( true );
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();

                try {

                    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    display.read(br, null);
                    br.close();
                    display.requestFocus();

                }

                catch(Exception error) {
                    System.err.println("Could'nt read a file");
                }
            }

          });

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error log?

Comment: No everytime i write onto a file it doesn't save my edits

Comment: you are only reading file but you haven't write edited content back to file

Comment: `display.setEditable ( false);`. How you will edit? And there is no save button also.

Comment: Also I set it to not allow changes for now and the question is how would i make a save button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should have another button say '**Save**' to save your edited content back to the file. For that you have to handle action on save button and write contents back to the file.

Comment: how does that work i have created the save button but can't seem to write back to the file

Comment: @JofhJyv - ofcourse it will not automatically save your content. you have to write actionListener on it like b1 button and put logic (get content of text area and write those content back to file) in it.

Comment: I've added the actionlistener now but what is the action it should perform

Comment: oh sorry didn't see you told me what to do

Comment: @JofhJyv - you should get content of text area and write those content back to file

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Random
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Press to read a file");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Save");
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
        final StringBuilder filename = new StringBuilder("");
        middlePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Text Reading Box"));

        // create the middle panel components

        final JTextArea display = new JTextArea(16, 58);
        display.setEditable(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(display);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // Add Text area in to middle panel
        middlePanel.add(scroll);

        // My code
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Reader 0.4 Beta");
        frame.add(middlePanel);
        frame.add(b1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(b2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                filename.append(f.getAbsolutePath());

                try
                {

                    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename.toString());
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    display.read(br, null);
                    br.close();
                    display.requestFocus();

                }

                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    System.err.println("Could'nt read a file");
                }
            }

        });
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String textToSet = display.getText();
                try
                {
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename.toString(), "UTF-8");
                    writer.write(textToSet);
                    writer.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException exc)
                {
                    System.err.println("Could'nt write to the file");
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```